# Clear canvas and memory wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a `Canvas` and I added 20000 `Line` objects to it as below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    var l = new Line
    {
        X1 = 10,
        Y1 = 10,
        X2 = 10,
        Y2 = 100,
        Stroke = Brushes.White
    };

    canvas.Children.Add(l);
}
```

Now let's say I want to remove these lines from the `Canvas`. I do this like below:

```
canvas.Children.Clear();
```

But this doesn't Clear the memory and it is like the data is stuck there. So when I add another 20000 `Line` objects the memory just explodes after some time.

I know that `Line` has overhead and I shouldn't use it in the first place but my problem is now in another area. How to clear the canvas of 20000 lines and draw new ones without increasing the memory.

Comment: Does the memory comes down or never? Are you sure that you don't have reference to those lines anywhere?

Comment: No, it only comes down when I use GC.Collect() manually.

Comment: When you say that memory usage goes down after GC.collect(), then it will also go down automatically. This happens when the garbage collection decides that it is time to clean up. You just haven't waited long enough, or haven't used enough other memory.

Comment: @Clemens I know but it doesn't go down. I'm really stuck here, any suggestions?

Comment: Then it is not a problem, memory will come down once when GC itself decides to run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you actually sure they're not going? I've just put the following demo application together.

[image]

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Name="canvas" Background="Black"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Add" Name="btnAdd" Click="btnAdd_Click" />
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Remove" Name="btnRemove" Click="btnRemove_Click"/>            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
            {
                var l = new Line
                {
                    X1 = 10,
                    Y1 = 10,
                    X2 = 10,
                    Y2 = 100,
                    Stroke = Brushes.White
                };

                canvas.Children.Add(l);
            }
        }

        private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            canvas.Children.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

And check the memory usage with Ants memory profiler (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

After pressing the add button and adding the lines, this is the instance list for line.
[image]

you can clearly see the line instances in that one, then after pressing remove you can see the line instances have completely gone as well as the memory usage going down on the graph at the top.

[image]

Comment: I was checking the Private Working Set in Task Manager, it didn't go down. Was I looking in the wrong place?